# Links aren't clickable in footer of WordPress site

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I've taken over a website that has to be live by tomorrow, however there's a fault somewhere preventing links from being clicked in the social media footer. It's a custom theme job and I don't have access to the original developers.

The Developer Tools view shows that the links are being passed back from the function alright, but I cannot seem to find where the error lies.

The site link is: http://developersinaction.com/projects/g1/thai-express

The footer code is:

```
<?php global $woocommerce, $thaiexpress_option; ?>
<div class="thaiexpress__footer-wrapper">
    <div class="thaiexpress__footer-border"></div>
    <?php get_template_part( 'instagram-feed' ); ?>
    <div class="thaiexpress__footer-details">
        <div class="container">

            <?php 
            $socials = $thaiexpress_option['thaiexpress__social_media_links'];
            if ( (array) $socials && isset($socials) ) : ?>
            <div class="thaiexpress__footer-social-lins">
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach ( (array) $socials as $key => $entry ) :
                    if ( !empty( $entry['url'] ) ) { ?>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo esc_url( $entry['url'] ) ?>"><?php echo (!empty($entry['thumb'])) ? '<img src="'.$entry['thumb'].'">' : ''; ?> <?php echo $entry['title']; ?></a></li>
                    <?php } endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="thaiexpress__footer-subscription-form">
                <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="97" title="Footer Form"]' ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thaiexpress__information-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                    <nav class="thaiexpress__footer-nav">
                        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'footer_nav','menu_id' => 'primary_nav' ) ); ?>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 thaiExpress__footer_nav_right">
                    <?php echo empty($thaiexpress_option['footer-credit']) ? "" : '<p>'. $thaiexpress_option['footer-credit'] .'</p>'; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 thaiExpress__footer_copyright">
                    <?php echo empty($thaiexpress_option['footer-copyright']) ? "" : '<p>'. $thaiexpress_option['footer-copyright'] .'</p>'; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- // end of .thaiexpress__footer-wrapper -->
```

I'm sure it's something really obvious but my eyes are seriously failing right now! Any help gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a div above the social footer that is covering your social links.

```
<div class="thaiexpress__testimonial-slide-wrap">...</div>
```

That div has margin-bottom:-202px. 
Remove that bottom margin and make the bottom padding much smaller.

You will then see #THAIEXPRESS_UK which was previously hidden, but maybe that's a bonus?